# Use Google Script to count dates in a column equal to a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, count

I have been using VBA for years, but I have had some extreme difficulty converting to google script and javascript.  I am trying to create an invoice number based on invoice date, taking into consideration previous entries with the same date, using the format YYMMDD## (e.g. 3 invoices on 11/13/2018 would create invoice numbers 18111301, 18111302, and 18111303) in Google Sheets.  I cannot use a formula for this particular situation.

I have spent the last 3 days digging through posts and GS tutorials without success.  I have GOT to be missing something.  I know this has to be some quick fix for something seriously easy to do, but I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

In this current iteration, I tried converting the search value and dataset to a Date format, but I have tried it without the conversion.  I apologize if the notes seem copious.  I start mapping each step when things go wrong.

```
function testbed0() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dte = ss.getActiveCell().getValue() //invoice date entered by user in column 1
  var cdte = Date(dte); //???convert cell value for comparison to date
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(1, 1, lrow, 1); //set range to first column, rows 1 to last with data
  var data = Date(r.getValues()); //???convert dataset to date format

  var count = 0; //start counter at 0
  //compare variable with dataset & increase counter for matches
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == cdte) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return (count);

  //parts of invoice number
  var invDy = ("0" + (dte.getDate())).slice(-2);
  var invMo = ("0" + (dte.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var invYr = ("0" + (dte.getYear())).slice(-2);
  var invCt = ("0" + count).slice(-2);

  //enter new invoice number in invoice column of active row
  ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).setValue(invYr+invMo+invDy+invCt);
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the output for this gives the correct format, but invCt always reads 00.

Comment: Please add this comment to your post using the `edit` link

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for but it accomplishes the same thing and perhaps it will help you to move further.  I formatted column one to be plain text.  This calculates all of the invoice numbers from top to bottom of the data.

```
function makeInvoiceNumbers(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var actRow=sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    var cnt=0;
    for(var j=1;j<i;j++){//Working from top to bottom creating invoice numbers
      if(vA[i][0]==vA[j][0]){//I assume that the entrees on the top came before the entrees below them.
        cnt++;
      }
    }
    vA[i][1]=getInvoiceString(vA[i][0].toString(),cnt);
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
function getInvoiceString(d,n){
  var dA=d.split('/');
  var yy=dA[2].toString().slice(2);//gets the last two digits of a four digit year
  var mm=padFor2Digits(dA[0]);
  var dd=padFor2Digits(dA[1]);
  var nn=padFor2Digits(String(n));
  return yy+mm+dd+nn;
}
function padFor2Digits(s){
  if(s.length<2){
    s='0' + s;
  }
  return s
}
```

Data before running makeInvoiceNumbers()

[image]

Data after running makeInvoiceNumbers()

[image]

If I were doing this for myself I would probably use the onEdit trigger and just do it for one line at a time.